# mkdir in ant fails. How can i handle this error

Tags: java, ant, mkdirs

The ANT build script I have does the following:

1. Perform the builds on Windows server & Zip the binaries
2. Map a network drive with different credentials to a local drive (ex P:) using `net use`
3. I am using `<mkdir>` to create a directory on the mounted drive (P:)
4. Copy the binaries to that drive

Below is my code for `mkdir`

```
<echo>Creating ${buildRequesterUserId} folder at mirroring site starts</echo>
<mkdir dir="P:\build_output\${buildRequesterUserId}"/>
<echo>Creating ${buildRequesterUserId} folder at mirroring site ends</echo>
```

Some time the creation of folder works and some time it fails with below error

`creation was not successful for an unknown reason` and makes the build fail

This error happens randomly. The Mkdir works some time. I am not sure why it fails and not sure if its because of network lag

also the directory i am trying to create may or may not exist already. I read that the mkdir does not do anything if directory exists already

I checked and there is no `failonerror` for mkdir. I don't want the build to fail because of this.

I have handled the error in `copy` part but not sure how to handle this `mkdir`

How can I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated

Regards

Karthik

Comment: if you don't mind could you please comment on my answer and describe which part of it resolved the issue for you (if it really resolved it :)

Comment: do you have write permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Ant `Mkdir` task is calling `File.mkdirs()` method which is [vulnerable to race conditions](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4742723).

`File.mkdirs()` is not an atomic operation - I guess it is implemented as a sequence of `mkdir` calls.

In case of a remote filsystem there's a good chance that your host gets aware of filesystem changes in the middle of `File.mkdirs()` operation and it fails.

Ant seemed to try to fix it as `Mkdir` code changed from this in [1.8.0](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/ant/ant-1.8.0/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Mkdir.java.html)

```
boolean result = mkdirs(dir);
if (!result) {
  String msg = "Directory " + dir.getAbsolutePath()
         + " creation was not successful for an unknown reason";
  throw new BuildException(msg, getLocation());
}
```

to this in [1.8.2](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/ant/ant-1.8.2/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Mkdir.java.html)

```
boolean result = mkdirs(dir);
if (!result) {
  if (dir.exists()) {
    log("A different process or task has already created "
         + "dir " + dir.getAbsolutePath(),
         Project.MSG_VERBOSE);
    return;
  }
  String msg = "Directory " + dir.getAbsolutePath()
         + " creation was not successful for an unknown reason";
  throw new BuildException(msg, getLocation());
}
```

so maybe upgrading to the latest Ant could help?

If not - some brute force `Mkdir` task extension could be created with your own `execute()` method implementation.

If not - [Trycatch task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/trycatch.html) from Ant Contrib will work.

Comment: Upgrading the ANT. I tested with 1.7x this still fails. I have not tried TryCatch as I don't have AntContrib. but I think this will also help me in capturing the error

Comment: he said the change was between 1.8.0 and 1.8.2, so upgrading to 1.7.x won't help...

Answer (score 2):

For me, I had a similar issue with the 1.9 version of ant.

I was deleting a directory and immediately re-creating it:

```
<delete dir="${jar.dir}"/>
<mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
```

Even though the directory was local (not a network drive), adding a sleep of 1 second between both operations fixed the issue for me:

```
<delete dir="${jar.dir}"/>
<sleep seconds="2"/>
<mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the COPY Task for creating directories (inclusive subdirectories).

Answer (score 0):

For me fixing the issue in linux was as simple as running as sudo user

"sudo ant"

Answer (score -4):

Here's how I solved it:

1. Open your build.properties file (Actually open all properties files'
   referenced from build.xml)
2. Check for any trailing spaces and tabs on any line of the file.
3. Add an additional blank line to the end of file.

Comment: May I know whats the rationale behind this?