# Unable to create folder "classes" in WEB_INF folder in eclipse while building using ANT

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build, project

I am using ANT to build a simple web application project named "HelloWebApp" in eclipse. But while using ANT to build the build.xml file I am getting the following error.

```
    Buildfile: C:\Users\bimal\workspace\HelloWebApp\build.xml
clean:
     [echo] Cleaning the build  
init:
     [echo] Creating the build directory

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\bimal\workspace\HelloWebApp\build.xml:18: Directory C:\Users\bimal\workspace\HelloWebApp\build  \WEB-INF\classes creation was not successful for an unknown reason

Total time: 849 milliseconds
```

The section in build.xml file which causes error is given below.

```
<target name="init" depends="clean">`  
<echo>Creating the build directory</echo>
<mkdir dir="${build.dir}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
<mkdir dir="${build.dir}/WEB-INF/lib"/>
<mkdir dir="${dist.dir}"/>
</target>
```

Please provide me solution for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the value of build.dir.  Please share content of your ant build file too.  I see a space after build in the value of your build.dir variable.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290591/mkdir-in-ant-fails-how-can-i-handle-this-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure that everyone has read/write permissions on that folder, use the windows permission tab on the preferences menu in the folder to check out if that's right.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it, I have tried and still its not working.

Comment: well, right click on the folder where you are saving the stuff, search through the menus until you find permissions, advanced, and from there you'll find out what to do, it's pretty simple. I'd show you more in detail but as of right now i'm on a mac LOL,  anyway you can also write  " change folder permissions windows "in google